# Java Web-App unable to run

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty

Jetty was running just fine, I think I accidentally did something ( I don't know what) and now it won't work anymore. I'm getting the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it please?

Comment: It's complaining about missing jars in your server classpath, ones related to JSP support.  How are you using Jetty Distribution? embedded-jetty? etc? (need more information about how your Jetty instance is started)

Comment: I downloaded and installed the jetty plugin on Intellij and then I set it's file paths and finally I set up the maven run to deploy using jetty:run each time I press run

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing jars in your project. You can implement this maven dependency and I think your problem would be solved.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
<version>6.0.45</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also download the jar here...

Comment: Wrong dependency for Jetty.  he needs `org.mortbay.jasper:apache-jsp:8.033`